# Pickle can't pickle a namedtuple

Tags: python, pickle, namedtuple

I am trying to pickle the `namedtuple` like this:

```
def f():
    TemplateData = namedtuple('TemplateData', ['field1', 'field2'])
    f1 = np.random.randn(50,50)
    f2 = np.random.randn(50,50)
    td = TemplateData(f1, f2)
    return td

data = f()
with open("aaaa.pkl", "wb") as fl:
    pkl.dump(data, fl)
```

but this crashes due to error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.TemplateData'>: it's not the same object as __main__.TemplateData
```

What's wrong?
If `pickle` is not the best way to store named tuple - what is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the namedtuple outside of your function, and change the name of your namedtuple to `TemplateData`.

```
TemplateData = namedtuple('TemplateData', ['field1', 'field2'])
f1 = np.random.randn(50,50)
f2 = np.random.randn(50,50)
model_cluster = TemplateData(f1, f2)

with open("aaaa.pkl", "wb") as fl:
    pkl.dump(model_clusters_dict, fl)
```

Comment: ahh, i get it, the class it tries to find class "TemplatedData" in my context, but can not, because the class is destroyed after the `f()` returns?

Comment: There's two things. One is that namedtuple isn't a class, it's a class factory that returns a class, which you in turn use to make instances. And the second is that pickle can't see the class definition if it's inside a function, because it's not in the global namespace.