# Python 3.9: unpickling of IsoCalendarDate data returns a tuple

Tags: python, pickle, python-datetime, python-3.9

Consider the following discussion / feature in Python3.9:
https://bugs.python.org/issue24416

In short, it was decided that the result of `datetime.date.isocalendar` would be changed to a `namedtuple` instead of `tuple`.

Now, I can see the benefit in doing that, but they also decided "to pickle" the new object (`datetime.IsoCalendarDate`) as a tuple:
https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/1b97b9b0ad9a2ff8eb5c8f2e2e7c2aec1d13a330#diff-2a8962dcecb109859cedd81ddc5729bea57d156e0947cb8413f99781a0860fd1R1214

So my question is, why did they make it so that creating the object directly, and "pickling-and-unpickling" the object require slightly different flows?

For example:

```
import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import pickle



RESULTS_CACHE_PICKLE = Path('cache.pickle')


if RESULTS_CACHE_PICKLE.is_file():
    with open(RESULTS_CACHE_PICKLE, 'rb') as f:
        icd = pickle.load(f)
else:
    icd = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1).isocalendar()
    with open(RESULTS_CACHE_PICKLE, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(icd, f)
        
        
print(icd.year)
```

Results in:

```
$ python icd_test.py
2019
$ python icd_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "icd_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(icd.year)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'year'
```

This inconsistency looks unstable to me. Does it happen in other places in the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, as suggested by *Batman* comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54837226/6573902):

> One is that `namedtuple` isn't a class, it's a **class factory** that
> returns a class, which you in turn use to make instances. (...)

And unfortunately, this is exactly the case (intentionally!) as we can read in the code of `IsoCalendarDate(tuple)` class:

```
def __reduce__(self):
    # This code is intended to pickle the object without making the
    # class public. See https://bugs.python.org/msg352381
    return (tuple, (tuple(self),))
```

So it seems that, for [some reason](http://%20https://bugs.python.org/msg352381), the inconsequential approach was taken intentionally but I am not aware of (m)any similar situations in Python code.

I think you can raise it as a bug. Maybe the rationale to keep `IsoCalendarDate` private from the `pickle` perspective should get revisited.